# Allow Flagging of a Profile

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I looked all over this profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6365681/saburdabar, and was unable to locate a "Flag for Moderator" button.

But as you can see, it's well needed:

## **Warning: Graphic!**

[image: heavily censored offensive profile]

So, I located one of his posts to flag for moderator attention, but there should be an easier way.

And if there is - then it should be *much more noticeable* and easier to find.

My proposal should be clear by now, but if it's not; please add a "Flag User" button within a user's profile.

Comment: Not just their profile: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48877400/revisions

Comment: @muru nice digging around. Good point

Comment: This has been asked many times, showing its  importance, but the original (see link above) is [tag:status-bydesign]. I think the team should have another look at this.

Comment: *Graphic???* You bleeped out all the good stuff. And now his account is gone. Thanks, you tease.

Comment: @Won't well.... you could always look at the revision history o.0

Comment: "S_t for B_stards" is literally the name of my high school garage band.